# Blocking IPv6 RA advertisements on Juniper EX series switch

Tags: juniper, ipv6, security, juniper-junos

How do I go about blocking IPv6 RA advertisements on access ports on a Juniper EX series switch? I know that Cisco offers ra-guard as an option much like bpdu-guard on spanning tree, I am just not sure how to accomplish the same thing in Junos.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The support for this feature looks a bit spotty depending on which version of Junos you're running.  You could try this:

```
term block-ra {
    from {
        icmp-type router-advertisement;
    }
    then {
        discard;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, but I think this would also block IPv4 Router Advertisements (ICMPv4 type 9). Adding 'from next-header icmpv6' would make the term match only IPv6 RAs as asked.